# Windows hosts: how can I redirect HTTPS site?

Tags: windows, https, hosts

I have the following in my `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

It works when I use: http://example.com

But does not work when I use: https://example.com, which gives error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Any idea how to use hosts with an HTTPS site?

If not, any alternative?

Comment: does https://example.com exists ?

Comment: Of course ! both http and https !

Comment: Of course. It’s specially reserved for use in documentation. However, I don’t see why it wouldn’t work for the OP except perhaps cached DNS information. Or are you referring to other trouble?

Comment: Well: Just test it : edit the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file and then test with http://www.example.com (works fine) and https://www.example.com (https version)  : gives error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Tunrs out that it would not work. [refer to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267921/how-to-add-entry-in-windows-host-file-such-that-it-can-redirect-over-https)

Comment: Sure it would work, @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like. But one would see certificate errors assuming one does not have the right certificate installed. (Not ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED errors.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following in your `hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

...makes both http://example.com and https://example.com go to 127.0.0.1, hence: your own machine. (Even more: *anything* that refers to `example.com`, such as `ping` or `telnet` would go to 127.0.0.1 when run from your computer.)

Apparently you have a web server running on your own computer on port 80 (HTTP), but nothing on port 443 (HTTPS). Even more, getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` actually proves your `hosts` file is used, as otherwise you would see [the default website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOorq.png) from https://example.com.

Note that if you would have the server on your computer also support HTTPS on port 443, you'd get certificate errors, as there is no way *you* can buy a certificate for the domain `example.com`.

Comment: I run now my apache on port 443 so I can access : http://127.0.0.1:443/
However https://example.com is not redirected to my local host.

Do you mean if I had a HTTPS running on my localhost, It would not change anything and still have that error ? 

So NO WAY to do that ?

Comment: If `https://127.0.0.1:443` works, then `https://example.com` and `https://example.com:443` should work too, @yarek. That is: it should give you an "invalid certificate" error/warning as the browser expects the certificate of `example.com`, but it should be able to connect. I think... Maybe restart the browser (or use another one) to make sure it has not cached the real IP address of `example.com`. Or try with another domain name.

Comment: (See my edit, @yarek: getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` actually proves your `hosts` file is used, as otherwise you would see [the default website](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gOorq.png) from https://example.com.)

Comment: Ah, @yarek, are you saying you have plain HTTP (not HTTPS) on port 443? That would surely confuse a browser when it tries to open a `https://` URL, but then is not able to actually *use* SSL. (For simplicity, that's kind of the same as using an `ftp://` URL in a browser, but the browser then encountering a web server instead of an FTP server on port 21.)

Comment: So, @yarek, does the above make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I got tricked thinking that the site serves traffic via https://example.com where in fact the URL is using a subdomain e.g. https://**www**.example.com
In that case just add one more record to the hosts file with www.example.com like below:

```
127.0.0.1   example.com
127.0.0.1   www.example.com
```

Or in fact to avoid errors on local web server (if you are running one for development purposes)

```
0.0.0.0 example.com
0.0.0.0 www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The following in your hosts file, working for me:

```
127.0.0.1 https://example.com
127.0.0.1 https://www.example.com
```